# How to collect entire <td> inner html with id="tripDate" in an array, and perform checking each td values with current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, innerhtml

How to collect entire td's inner html with id="tripDate" in an array, and perform checking each td values with current date either by using JavaScript or by jquery.

```
<table class="w3-table-all w3-small w3-responsive"> 
    <thead>
        <tr class="w3-green">
            <th style="padding:15px; font-weight:bold;">Departure Dates</th>
            <th style="padding:15px; font-weight:bold;">Departure Availablity</th>
            <th style="padding:15px; font-weight:bold;">Trip Cost</th>
            <th style="padding:15px; font-weight:bold;">Inquiry</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
     <tr class="w3-hover-pale-green">
        <td id="tripDate"><?=$ddate1='March, 21, 2017 - April, 06, 2017'?></td>
        <td class="available">Available</td>
        <td>USD$ 1250.00</td>
        <td><a class="w3-btn w3-small w3-green w3-hover-green fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="<?=ROOTDIR.$_PHPLIB['contact']?>index.php?trpName=<?=$tripName?>&trpDate=<?=$ddate1;?>&trpUrl=<?=$actual_link;?>">Inquiry</a></td>
     </tr>       
     <tr class="w3-hover-pale-green">
        <td id="tripDate"><?=$ddate1='March, 28, 2017 - April, 13, 2017'?></td>
        <td class="available">Available</td>
        <td>USD$ 1250.00</td>
        <td><a class="w3-btn w3-small w3-green w3-hover-green fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="<?=ROOTDIR.$_PHPLIB['contact']?>index.php?trpName=<?=$tripName?>&trpDate=<?=$ddate1;?>&trpUrl=<?=$actual_link;?>">Inquiry</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="w3-hover-pale-green">
        <td id="tripDate"><?=$ddate1='April, 04, 2017 - April, 20, 2017'?></td>
        <td class="available">Available</td>
        <td>USD$ 1250.00</td>
        <td><a class="w3-btn w3-small w3-green w3-hover-green fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="<?=ROOTDIR.$_PHPLIB['contact']?>index.php?trpName=<?=$tripName?>&trpDate=<?=$ddate1;?>&trpUrl=<?=$actual_link;?>">Inquiry</a></td>
     </tr>  
</table>
```

```js
var currentDate = new Date();   
var IDs = [];

$('.w3-table-all').find("td[id='tripDate']").each(function() { 
    IDs.push(this.id);
});

$.each(IDs, function(index, value) {
    var actualDates = document.getElementById(value).innerHTML;
    // didn't get all the values something went wrong ?????
    if (actualDates < currentDate) {
        //do something good
    }   
});
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id` which is invalid and the main cause of your problem. Change them to a class instead. You can also then use `map()` to build your array. You will also have a problem converting the values of the `td` to dates which can be compared, as their current values cannot be directly parsed to Date objects. You will need to do some string hacking to make it work. I suggest you research Date parsing in JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you should write a book on map() :P

Comment: @Mahi it's my favourite jQuery method :)

Answer (score 1):

You iterate like following:

```
var now = new Date();

 $(".w3-table-all td[id='tripDate']").each(function() {
        var currentTripDateRange = this.innerText
          , currentTripDates = currentTripDateRange.split(' - ')
          , startDate =Date.parse(currentTripDates[0])
          , lastDate =Date.parse(currentTripDates[1]);

      if(now >= startDate && now <= lastDate){
          //here is your selected dateRange
          log(currentTripDateRange);
      }
    });
```

Find the working code here: http://jsbin.com/juqomonuci